Check the Integration process for this integration: $\int_0^s \exp\left(-ax+\frac bx\right)~dx$
I am trying to integrate
$\int_0^s \exp\left(-ax+\frac bx\right)~dx$.
I proceed in this way (according to Primitive of $ \exp(-a \times x- \frac bx)$):
$=\int_0^s \exp(-ax-(\frac {(-b)}{x})~)~dx$
$=s\int_1^\infty\dfrac{exp({-\frac{(-b)x}{s}-\frac{as}{x}})}{x^2}~dx$
$=sK_1\left(\dfrac{(-b)}{s},as\right)$ (according to https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf)
$K_1(x,y)$ is a incomplete besselK function.
Please check my integration process, is it correct or not ?
I am unable to verify it on Mathematica. Also I want to implement this incomplete besselK function on MATLAB.
